# C++ Arduino: After downcasting, child fields do not reference the original addresses

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, arduino

## Arduino: C++

I have the following classes: `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` inherit from `Parent`, `ChildTwo` has fields specific to it.

```cpp
const byte TYPE_1 = 0;
const byte TYPE_2 = 1;
const byte TYPE_3 = 2;

class Parent {
   private:
    byte type = TYPE_1;

   public:
    Parent(byte type) : type(type) {}
};

class ChildOne : public Parent {
   public:
    ChildOne() : Parent(TYPE_2) {}
};

class ChildTwo : public Parent {
   public:
    ChildTwo() : Parent(TYPE_3) {}

    boolean isOn = false;
    char* textOn = "ON";
    char* textOff = "OFF";
};
```

The problem I face is that when I create an array of type parent and add elements of `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` and I get one element from the array and try to do a `static_cast`, it succeeds, but when I print the values of the fields specific to `ChildTwo`, the values are funny ASCII characters

**e.g.**

```cpp
Parent menu[] = {ChildOne(), ChildTwo(), ChildOne()};

Parent item = menu[1];

if (item.type == TYPE_3) {

    ChildTwo* child = static_cast<ChildTwo*>(&item);
    ...
}
```

After type casting, when I print the values of the fields in `child` object:

```cpp
    ...
    Serial.print(child->isOn);
    Serial.print(child->textOn);
    ....
```

the values printed on the serial monitor are different from **0** and **ON** respectively *(instead, I see funny ASCII chars).* *they point to different addresses*

I want to know if there is anything I'm doing wrong.

What do I do to obtain my objective?

> **NB**: I believe `dynamic_cast` will work but the compiler for **Arduino Uno** doesn't support it.

‏‏‎ ‎
‏‏‎ ‎
‏‏‎ ‎
‏‏‎ ‎
‏‏‎ ‎

---

*I am blocked from asking any more questions because of questions I posted about 4 yrs ago. The only option they gave me was to update my old questions (4 years old questions, that doesn't seem right), I no longer face those problems and the comments/answers will look irrelevant to people viewing now after the update.*

Comment: Can you verify, that `check_refresh` is located in `res/drawable` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the file `res/drawable/check_refresh.xml`: that's the crash being reported. It might be in a version specific folder: what's the path from the project root? I expect you have some drawables in a v21 folder or something.

Comment: Sorry, don't mean version control like git: I mean versioned like inside a  *res/drawable-v21* folder.